# Combine csv files to one csv file in Python 3

Tags: python, python-3.x, csv

I am a Python beginner but i would like to ask something that i did not find in the forum.

I have multiple csv files into a folder which contain data like this (structure is identical to all of them):

File1.csv

```
Original
7200
118800
0
-955.8
7075
1080
115628.57
3171.4
```

File2.csv

```
Renovated
20505
4145
0
55
7075
103
22359
4145
```

And so on.

I would like to make a script in Python 3 that copies them to one csv file one column after another. Could you offer me please some help?

Comment: have you tried anything?

Comment: show the desired result

Comment: I would recommend looking at the pandas module and the functions to_csv and read_csv and concat. I would probably just do this with the unix tools `tr` and `cat` myself.

Comment: In the resulting `csv` file, do you want everything in one long column, or each file added into a new column?

Comment: The assistance of Brad Solomon was great, the solution works like a charm.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Say your files are named File1.csv, File2.csv, and File3.csv.

```
import pandas as pd

pieces = []
for num in [1, 2, 3]:
    s = pd.read_csv('folder/subfolder/File%d.csv' % num) # your directory
    pieces.append(s)
newcsv = pd.concat(pieces, axis=1) # this will yield multiple columns
newcsv.to_csv('folder/subfolder/newcsv.csv')
```

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you have pandas installed and import it like this :

```
import pandas as pd
```

Read your two different csv using `pd.read_csv()`:

```
df1=pd.read_csv('file1.csv')
df2=pd.read_csv('file2.csv')
```

Then add an other column to your first dataframe using (make sure it's the same size):

```
df1['Renovated'] = pd.Series(df2['Renovated'],index=df1.index)
```

In the df1 you should now have two columns do it for as many csv you have.

To finish to save your final csv with all columns just do :

```
df1.to_csv('finalName.csv', index=False)
```